# Help with (big) numbers including 'decena'

Tags: contemporary-latin, numbers

I wonder if you could help me with the text below. I get the gist of the message, but am struggling with *decena*.

> Nam decēna mīlia Americānōrum cōnāta sunt ad centiēs centēna mīlia dollāriōrum raedāriīs mittere Canadēnsibus.

My translation:

> For ten thousand Americans tried to send 10 million dollars to the truck drivers.

Am I right in thinking that Latin doesn't have numbers for "million, billion" so uses an adverb e.g. 10 million = one hundred times (*centies* - adv) one hundred (*centena* - adj) thousand.

Where I struggle is the *decena*. Is this an adverb (surely it should be *deciens*?) or an adjective (surely it should be *decima*) or something else?

I have taken this from Nuntii Latini so this is very much nova latina, but I presume entirely correct.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does "ad" mean in "ad centiēs..."?

Comment: @Vegawatcher Probably "approximately".

Answer (score 5):

Latin has four kinds of numerals:
For quantity (*quattuor*, four),
for order (*quartus*, fourth),
for number of times (*quater*, four times),
and lot size (*quaterni*, four at a time).

Thus *ter quaterni equi* would mean three lots of four horses each.
Or, if you ignore the internal structure, simply twelve horses.
You can think of *quaterni* as an adjective modifying *equi* and of *ter* as an adverb modifying *quaterni*.

This is the idea behind *centies centena milia*, or a hundred lots of a hundred thousand each, or ten million.
Classical Latin does indeed seem to lack an established word for a million, so they used this method of expressing multiples of a hundred thousand instead.

When you don't use an adverbial number like *centies* to tell how many lots of thousands you have, you should not use the distributive version *dena* (for which I assume *decena* is a error by analogy to *vicena* etc.) but simply *decem*.
The sentence should have had *decem milia* instead of *dena milia*, unless the message is somehow that ten thousand Americans at a time sent some money.
You are right to struggle with *decena* as it is both ill-formed and ill-chosen!

Comment: I upvoted your answer for completeness and clarity.   However, after recently discovering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_numerals, I think it would be better to say that the question mentions four types of Latin numerals, rather than stating only four types exist in Latin.

Comment: @Vegawatcher As far as I can tell, the tradition is to say that Latin has four kinds of numerals and treat the other things as derived adjectives. Such classifications are a matter of taste, of course.

Comment: I confirmed the tradition of four kinds of numerals in materials I had handy and will post the question.